# How to store a NULL value in a vector?

Tags: r

Im running an API script from R which returns a numeric value everytime is called. Im storing that value on a vector using a loop

```
i=1
a=""
idPaciente = NULL
for (i in 1:length (poblacion1)) {

  
  a = consulta_idPaciente(poblacion1[i])
  print(a)
  idPaciente[i] <- a 

  }
```

Sometimes the API will return a NULL value when there is no output from the server for that specific API input. this is causing the following error

```
NULL
Error in idPaciente[i] <- a : replacement has length zero
```

I would like to store the NULL anyways in the vector since that absense of data means something to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `NULL` values and assign `NA` to the output.

```
i=1
a=""
idPaciente = numeric(length(poblacion1))

for (i in seq_along(poblacion1)) {
  a = consulta_idPaciente(poblacion1[i])
  if(is.null(a)) idPaciente[i] <- NA
  else idPaciente[i] <- a
}
```